# SQL syntax error in trigger

Tags: mysql, syntax, triggers, mariadb

Can someone tell me what this sql does not work? Where is the syntax error?

```
SET NEW.`modified` = CURTIME() WHERE `id` = NEW.id;
```

Error:

One or more errors have occured while processing your request: 
The following query has failed:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `event_name` 
BEFORE UPDATE ON `clients` 
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.`modified` = CURTIME() WHERE `id` = NEW.id;
```

> MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'WHERE `id` = NEW.id' at line 1

Image shows the error
http://s23.postimg.org/rhsf2x1tn/screenshot.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `where` condition to specify the row being changed.

For every row being updated, you set the specific column value. See the example below as well as the quoted reference.

**Quoting/Referencing from [here](http://themattreid.com/wordpress/2012/11/26/simple-mysql-using-triggers-to-keep-datetime-columns-updated-without-direct-sql-calls/):**

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER event_name BEFORE UPDATE ON clients 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    SET NEW.date_modify = NOW();
END; 
|
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: thank you! finally it works, I thought i have to put WHERE as well, but apparently I was mistaken! Many thanks